# Passing Web Service Url to Flex 3 using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, apache-flex, flex3

I am using Flex Builder 3 and visual studio 2010
I have created webService.asmx and default.aspx.
I want to use this swf file in default.aspx. 
I want to pass web service url dynamically to my swf file.
my mxml contains this code

```
    <mx:WebService id="webService" 
    wsdl=""
    useProxy="true"
    fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString), 'Error'">
        <mx:operation name="addData" 
            resultFormat="object"                
            result="AddRecord();" 
            />
</mx:WebService>
```

I want to pass wsdl dynamically
i.e http://localhost:12345/flexProject/WebService.asmx?wsdl to my `<mx:WebService wsdl="">`

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Flashvars](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_3.html).